# Making dictionary access thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, thread-safety

whats is the easiest way to make C# dictionary access thread safe? Preferably just using lock(object) but any other ideas welcome!

Answer (score 61):

In .NET 4 you have the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) class.

If you need to use an older version of .NET, and want to write it yourself:

- wrap a Dictionary as a **private** field in your class
- use a separate `private object lockObject`
- take a lock on that `lockObject` around every access to the dictionary

Comment: Just wonder, why "use a seperate lock object"?

Comment: @MonoLightTech - a bit theoretical, but if code inside the Dictionary class itself or external code that needs to 'see' the collection also locks on it, you might have a deadlock. Use separation of concerns: the lockObject is for locking only.