# How to use a dictionary in a multi threading application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dictionary

Alright i have an application which starts hundreds of crawling tasks at the same time and those tasks adds hundreds of found urls into a dictionary

I am using lock to add each found url however i see that all threads are waiting at lock (it works but i am looking for faster working way if there is any)

I wonder are there any better way for me to improve performance

The application is .net 4.5.1 c#-5 WPF application

This is my dictionary definition

```
   private static Dictionary<string, UrlHolder> dicUrlHolder = new Dictionary<string, UrlHolder>();
```

This is how i use

```
lock (dicUrlHolder)
        {
//do stuff here each time gets a lock
        }
```

So i wonder any other better way to use it between hundreds of threads locking concurrently hundreds of times to add / update

Comment: Use `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: Like Vsevolod said ConcurrentDictionary would be good there. Answers about that can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940241/making-dictionary-access-thread-safe (and in the question this one is a duplicate of)

Comment: And of course: Inside the lock do nothing but modify the dictionary. All other statements before the lock

Comment: what exactly happens in `do stuff here each time gets a lock`?

Comment: yes i know ConcurrentDictionary  but is it really faster ? this article is really interesting as @ie mentioned : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548406/Dictionary-plus-Locking-versus-ConcurrentDictionar i read it before as well

Comment: _"... that all threads are waiting at lock"_ - they shouldn't be. You have another problem where you don't expect it. Locking on a normal Dictionary should be fine, esp with so much I/O going on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> Class`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG says that he has a performance issue here. Unfortunately, `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not always help. See for example [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548406/Dictionary-plus-Locking-versus-ConcurrentDictionar)